# Serivces no Android reinicializando as variáveis

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service

Eu desenvolvendo um aplicativo teste no qual um `Service` fica rodando em Background e fica enviando notificações para o celular a cada 10 segundos. Para melhorar o teste eu criei um contador que vai aumentando a cada notificação enviada. O `Service` funciona quase que perfeitamente, porem, se eu abrir e fechar o APP o contador reinicia pra 1 e eu não faço a menor ideia do porque.
Eu falei em fechar o APP e não minimizar, existe uma grande diferença entre minimizar o APP e fechar, se eu minimizar continua normal porem se eu fechar ele ai sim o contador reinicia.

Classe do serviço:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public sattic int j = 1;


   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(BackgroundService.this)
                            .setContentTitle("Notificação: " + j)
                            .setContentText("Texto da notificação: " + j)
                            .setTicker("Texto que aparece ao receber a notificação.")
                            .setBadgeIconType(R.drawable.error)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.help)
                            .setAutoCancel(true);

                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
                     j++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        Log.create(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
   }
}
```

Classe Main:

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BackgroundService.class));
        }
}
```

Resumindo, se eu abrir o aplicativo o contador e as notificações funcionam normalmente, porem se eu fechar o aplicativo o contador reinicia do 1 (as notificações continuam aparecendo porem o contador reinicia). Eu falei em fechar o APP e não minimizar, existe uma grande diferença entre minimizar o APP e fechar, se eu minimizar continua normal porem se eu fechar ele ai sim o contador reinicia.

Eu já tentei colocar a variável do contador dentro da `Thread` porém não funcionou ele reinicia do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Não entendi. Não é natural que reinicie?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Então você esta me dizendo que é normal que reinicie? Se eu tivesse ali em vez de um int um Socket eu ia perder a conexão? Ou se eu tivesse salvo um nome de usuario também por exemplo, eu ia perde-lo só porque ele fechou o App?

Answer (score 0):

é normal que reinicie, toda vez que o service for ativado, ele irá criar uma nova instancia do Service com os valores padrões da classe, se você quiser fazer um contador com o valor antigo, sugiro que armazene o valor atual toda vez que terminar de executar o Service e acesse esse valor quando iniciar o Service

aqui está algumas opções de Armazenamento de dados no Android para fazer isso

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=pt-br

Comment: Mas e se eu tiver objetos não serializaveis que não podem ser armazenados? Eu vou perder essas informações se o cara fechar o APP? Achei que a ideia do Service era justamente funcionar em segundo plano. Existe alguma maneira de assegurar ou manter esses objetos?

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada na documentação e o serviço só instanciado uma vez, e nessa oportunidade o método onCreate() é chamado e logo em seguida o método onStartCommand(), quando ele for "instanciado" novamente então o método onCreate() não sera chamado apenas o método onStartCommand(). Então não faz sentido isso, ou talvez eu entendi errado a documentação.